# Compiling .java Files in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, build, compilation

I have imported .java files into Eclipse- Kepler and made changes, but I cannot seem to compile them. The Project menu has Build Automatically checked, but I still have no class files where I would expect them . My reputation is too low to attach a screen capture to demonstrate what I changed. Any suggestions you have would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Java sources are only compiled if put in a source folder inside a Java project.  Consider putting a screen shot elsewhere and provide the link.